# How to iterate over a dictionary using for loops?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to decompress a dictionary and a list into a sentence. For example:

```
newlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
new_dictionary = {'code': 2, 'help': 6, 'broken': 4, 'is': 3, 'please': 5, 'my': 1}
```

The original sentence is `'My code is broken please help'`. The list shows the positions that the words appear within the sentence. The dictionary stores the word and the position that the word associates with.

The goal is to iterate over the dictionary until the  matches the number in the list. Once this happens, the key that matches to the value is added to a list. This will continue to happen until there are no more numbers in the list. The list is then converted into a string and printed to the user.

I would imagine that something like this would be the solution:

```
for loop in range(len(newlist)):
    x = 0
    for k,v in new_dictionary.items():
         if numbers[x] == v:
              original_sentence.append(k)
         else:
              x = x + 1

print(original_sentence)
```

However, the code just prints an empty list. Is there any way of re-wording or re-arranging the for loops so that the code works?

Comment: Why not invert the dictionary, so it maps position to word instead of word to position? Then this is trivial.

Comment: What is the actual use case? What is this code supposed to be doing? What are you using this for? Also what do you mean by `The goal is to iterate over the dictionary until the matches the number in the list`

Comment: Your code would not work at all as `original_sentence` and `numbers` are not defined. Please post the _actual_ code you are working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you don't want to invert the dictionary, so you can try something like this:

```
dictionary = {'code': 2, 'help': 6, 'broken': 4, 'is': 3, 'please': 5, 'my': 1}
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

sentence = []
for number in numbers:
    for key in dictionary.keys():
        if dictionary[key] == number:
            sentence.append(key)
            break
```

Answer (score 4):

Invert the dictionary and proceed. Try the following code.

```
>>> d = {'code': 2, 'help': 6, 'broken': 4, 'is': 3, 'please': 5, 'my': 1}
>>> numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> d_inv = {v:k for k,v in d.items()}
>>> ' '.join([d_inv[i] for i in numbers])
'my code is broken please help'
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorted the dict with using the values.

```
import operator
new_dictionary = {'code': 2, 'help': 6, 'broken': 4, 'is': 3, 'please': 5, 'my': 1}
sorted_x = sorted(new_dictionary.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
print ' '.join(i[0] for i in sorted_x)
```

**result**

```
'my code is broken please help'
```

The whole code in single line.

```
In [1]: ' '.join([item[0] for item in sorted(new_dictionary.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))])
Out[1]: 'my code is broken please help'
```

Comment: This works great but the OP is looking for the sentence in the order defined in the list named `newlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`. It just happens to be sorted in the example.

Comment: @AbdulFatir You are right . It's only work if the desired list in the form of a acceding order.